# Data does not get inserted into the table sometime

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, struts, oracle11g

I have a table A. I insert data into table A through a user interface. Table A has an ID(primary key), which is generated using a sequence, and 16 other columns. One of the column is called cntrct_no.

When I try to insert data into the table through UI, it works fine the first time. I check the table A and all the data are there.

But when I try to insert the same data again without changing anything, it looks like the data is getting added to the table and I do not get any errors. But when I check table A, the data inserted the second time is not there.

If I try to insert the same data directly thorough SQL developer, the data gets inserted into the table.

The weird thing is if I just change the value of the cntrct_no in the UI and leave rest of the data same, the data gets inserted.

Can anyone please explain to me what could possibly cause this?

Not sure if this helps: stmt.executeUpdate(); returns 0 when the data is not inserted and a 1 when it's inserted.

```
public void writeToAudit(String contractNo, String tripNo, 
        String tripEffDate, 
        String tripDiscDate, String transpModeId, String userId, 
        String transType, AplLeg[] legs) {

    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Connection con = null;
    con = session.connection(); 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    PreparedStatement stmtSelId = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    long nextId = -1;
    int i=0;

    try {

        for(i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {

            String sqlNextId = "SELECT rpt_audit_transportation_seq.NEXTVAL as seqval FROM DUAL";
            stmtSelId = con.prepareStatement(sqlNextId, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = stmtSelId.executeQuery();
            rs.last();
            final int rows = rs.getRow();
            if (rows == 0){
                nextId = -1;
            }
            rs.beforeFirst();
            rs.next();
            nextId = rs.getInt(1);

            if(nextId==-1)
                throw new SQLException("Cannot get next val from rpt_audit_transportation sequence.");

            stmt = con.prepareStatement(WRITE_TO_AUDIT_DML);
            stmt.setLong(1, nextId);
            stmt.setString(2, userId.toUpperCase());
            stmt.setString(3, transType);
            stmt.setString(4, contractNo);
            stmt.setString(5, tripNo);
            stmt.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(transpModeId));
            stmt.setString(7, tripEffDate);
            stmt.setString(8, tripDiscDate);
            stmt.setLong(9, legs[i].getLegId().longValue());
            int temp =  stmt.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
        }

        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
        closeConnection(session, con, stmtSelId, rs);
    }
}
```

THE SQL STATEMENT:

```
private static final String WRITE_TO_AUDIT_DML =
    "INSERT INTO rpt_audit_transportation " + 
    "(audit_id, audit_date, audit_process, audit_userid, " +
    "audit_trans_type, audit_route_no, audit_trip_no, " +
    "audit_eff_dt, audit_disc_dt, audit_orig_facility_id, " +
    "audit_dest_facility_id, audit_arvl_tm, audit_dprt_tm, " +
    "audit_leg_seq_no, audit_freq_id, audit_trnsp_mode_id) " +
    "(SELECT ?, " +     // audit id
         "SYSDATE, " +
         "'TOPS_UI', " +
         "?, " +        // userId
         "?, " +
         "rte.cntrct_no, " +
         "trp.trip_no, " +
         "rte.cntrct_eff_dt, " +
         "rte.cntrct_disc_dt, " +
         "NVL(leg.orig_facility_id, trp.orig_fac_id), " +
         "NVL(leg.dest_facility_id, trp.dest_fac_id), " +
         "NVL(leg.arvl_tm, trp.arvl_tm), " +
         "NVL(leg.dprt_tm, trp.dprt_tm), " +
         "leg.leg_seq, " +
         "trp.freq_id, " +
         "rte.trnsp_mode_id " +
        "FROM apl_contract rte, " +
         "apl_trip trp, " +
         "apl_leg leg " +
        "WHERE rte.cntrct_no = ? " +        // contract id
          "AND trp.trip_no = ? " +          // trip no
          "AND rte.trnsp_mode_id = ? " +        // transp mode id
          "AND rte.cntrct_locked_ind = 'N' " +
          "AND trp.trip_eff_dt = to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY') " +            // trip eff date
          "AND trp.trip_disc_dt = to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY') " +           // trip disc date
          "AND trp.cntrct_id = rte.cntrct_id " +
          "AND leg.trip_id = trp.trip_id " +
          "AND leg.leg_id = ?) ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not inserting plain values, but a result of a select based on the parameters.
What you are using is an `INSERT ... SELECT ()` clause, so if the `SELECT` part does not return any rows, the `INSERT` won't insert anything, and `stmt.executeUpdate()` will return `0`. Find out why `SELECT` returns no rows.

This may be due some triggers saving stuff in other tables when you do the insert into `rpt_audit_transportation`, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Only after the data is successfully saved in these other tables, is the above method(writeToAudit()) called. So we're not violating any constraints in the other tables. Matter of face, the data appears in these other tables, just not in rpt_audit_transportation table.

Comment: In this case: Are you sure, that `writeToAudit()` is always called? Maybe it's a bug in your java code, resulting in this method not being called?

Comment: yes it's always called. I put break points to make sure of that. stmt.executeUpdate(); returns 0 when the data is not inserted and a 1 when it's inserted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a `catch` that is swallowing your exceptions

```
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

That means that when the SQL statement throws an error, you're telling your code to catch the exception and ignore it.  It is almost always an error to do that since, as you're discovering, it means that your code can fail to do what you expect with no way of letting you know that something failed.  At a minimum, you would need to log the exception somewhere.  In general, though, if you cannot fix whatever condition lead to the exception, you ought to re-raise the exception or simply not catch it in the first place.

My guess is that the second insert is violating some constraint defined on the table.  But since your code is catching the exception and throwing it away, you're not being notified that there was a constraint violation nor is your code noting which constraint was violated.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have some statements in the catch block. I didn't include it because I did not want to make this post too long. I put break point in the catch block to check if it gets hit. But it never does. As far as the constraint is concerned, the only constraint I can see on the table is the primary key.

Comment: @javaStudent - If you want to simplify the code you post, you'd probably be better served removing the exception handler entirely.  If you're stepping through the code in the debugger, does `int temp =  stmt.executeUpdate();` get executed a second time?  If so, how many rows does `temp` show you were inserted?

Comment: temp shows 1 when the data shows up in my table and 0 when it does not.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer - you are using `INSERT ... SELECT ()`, so if the `SELECT` part does not return any rows, the `INSERT` won't insert anything. Find out why `SELECT` returns no rows.

Comment: @npe I checked if the select part of the insert statement returns anything and it does return a row of data.

Comment: Talk to your DB admin and try to enable session tracing inside the database. Check whether this insert is being called at all from the database point of view, and what it does (there should be some clues in the trace-log, depending on what DB you are using).

Comment: And one more thing: is `rpt_audit_transportation` a regular table, or is it a view with `INSTEAD OF` triggers? If the latter, then perhaps those triggers are to blame?

Comment: @npe It's not a view. It's just a regular table.

Comment: I'm out of bullets... Check the trace-log.

Comment: @javaStudent - How did you determine that the `SELECT` statement returned a row of data?  Did you run the query in the same session as the `INSERT`?  Or was it in a different session?  Are you certain that the row was committed  and that your application's transaction isolation level allows you to see the row?

Comment: @JustinCave I changed the query string "WRITE_TO_AUDIT_DML". I took out the insert part and just left the select part. So instead of doing insert it just did select and saved the result in a ResultSet and then I checked the content of the resultSet.

Comment: @javaStudent - In the same session that the `INSERT` failed?  Or in a different session?

Comment: @JustinCave in the same insert session that failed.

Comment: @javaStudent - Can you update your question to have the actual test case that you're running that demonstrates that the `SELECT` returns a row immediately before the `INSERT ... SELECT` inserts 0 rows?  We're making a lot of guesses based on information you're providing in comments about code that we can't see.  Please simplify your code as much as possible but post the entire test (i.e. don't simply remove the code in exception handlers because you don't think it's important but feel free to remove the exception handlers entirely from your example).

Comment: @javaStudent - Is you can replicate the problem with a simpler SQL statement (i.e. insert data for 1 column rather than 10, select from 1 table rather than 3, use 1 bind variable rather than 9, etc.) that would make your test case easier to follow as well.  If you are debugging, tell us exactly what you see (or, better yet, print out data in the code you post and include the debug output from an execution of the code).

Answer (score 1):

1. When the `cntrct_no` is same you are getting an exception and you are supperessing that as told by @Justin Cave. This may be because you are having a unique constraint for that field and the DB throws an error and you are suppressing.
2. When `cntrct_no` is changed - obviously the constraint wont fail and for primary key since you are using the sequence it would have generated the next number and it happily gets inserted in the DB.

Don't ever suppress the exception. Do some thing in that block either rethrow as application specific exception or  convert to error code and propagate that to the front end.